# How to backorder a .io domain name

Tags: domains, domain-registration

There is a .io domain name I want to buy when it becomes available in 12 months time.

What is the best tool to buy this automatically?

Answer (score 2):

[I realize this doesn't answer your question directly, but then my point is that the *practical* answer is that your chances of this working are not great.]

What makes you think the domain's going to become available at all? And that you'll get at it before people whose *business* it is to snatch up expiring domains? If you actually want the domain, versus being willing to just take a gamble on it, you're best off contacting the current owner about acquiring it from them. (I'm assuming there's *something* in the way of contact information or a form available.)

A direct offer at least puts you at the front of the line. Placing a backorder doesn't promise anything, least of all being the only one trying. And then if there are multiple people, you could end up in an auction, which is a whole other game.

Comment: Thanks, I think the domain will come up as the company closed down after a few months of trading. I am talking to them about buying all of their assets as well but there is a chance it won't happen and the name will expire.